# Are random variables in a tail σ-algebra in the same probability space?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be random variables.

Define $\mathscr{T}_n = \sigma(X_{n+1}, X_{n+2}, ...)$ and $\mathscr{T} = \bigcap_{n} \mathscr{T}_n$, the tail σ-algebra of $X_1, X_2, ...$.

When defining a tail σ-algebra, need the random variables necessarily have the same probability space?

Let's say:

$X_n$ is defined on $(\Omega_n, \mathscr{F}_n, \mathbb{P}_n)$.

1. $\Omega_n$ --> Need the $\Omega_n$'s be the same ($\Omega \doteq \Omega_1$ = $\Omega_2$ = ...)?

Consider $\Omega_n = (H, T)$ for odd n and $\Omega_n = (HH, HT, TH, TT)$ or even n, where H stands for heads and T for tails in coin flipping.

Well I guess $\mathscr{T}_n$ may make sense but not $\mathscr{T}$?

2. $\mathscr{F}_n$ --> I think these are all under a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{F}$ which we know to exist since the $\mathscr{T}_n$'s are sub-$\sigma$-algebras of something.
3. $\mathbb{P}_n$ --> Need the $\mathbb{P}_n$'s be the same?

Consider $P(X_n = 1) = 1$ for odd n and $P(X_n = 1) = 1/2$ and $P(X_n = -1) = 1/2$ for even n.

Note: I know that this question may have some superfluous content since it is primarily focused on probability spaces rather than tail σ-algebras, which are merely the motivation for the question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, otherwise how do you plan on taking intersection of sets which don't live in the same space? You should think of random variable as just measurable functions, which then would be kinda odd if they didn't share the same domain. Perhaps a better question is how do we know that, given a sequence of random variable, that there is a probability space which can hold them all?

The short answer is yes: Certainly for each $X_n$, there is some $\Omega_n$ which can work. Now, just take a countable product of your $\Omega_n$, and justify that you can find a probability measure on this new space which agrees with each of your little spaces in such a way that your random variables (now extended to the product space) have the same law.

Comment: 'Yes, otherwise how do you plan on taking intersection of sets which don't live in the same space? ' --> Okay so that takes care of $\Omega$. What about $\mathbb{P}$? Like how about we just defined the random variables on a probable (probabilistic word for measurable) space rather than a probability (measure) space?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you only have one space, then you only have one $\mathbb{P}$. Also, I don't understand your distinction between "probable" space vs "probability (measure) space"?

Comment: Wait lol doesn't make sense sorry. How about we just define a tail sigma-algebra on a measurable space rather than a probability space?

Comment: Also, I think I read your question wrong initially. You mentioned that one CAN find a probability measure such that each RV has the same law, but NEED one find such?

Comment: The issue in your problem is that you have random variables, each with laws and whatnot. However, we want to think of them as functions from some big $\Omega$ into $\mathbb{R}$. You can easily come up with an $\Omega_n$ for each $X_n$, but you want a way to somehow "combine" them altogether, so that you only have one domain, the way you can actually compare the sigma algebras they generate.

Comment: Ah so it's something like we don't really need to technically, but there's not much point in talking about tail sigma-algebras if we don't?

Comment: How one can summarize the arguments above as the fact that every random variable being defined on the same probability space is "something like we don't really need to technically" is beyond my understanding, I must admit. The positive side of the episode, to me, is to put into context several previous, similar, ones.